# Iterating through multiple pandas Dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop

I have a forecasting function which I have applied to one dataframe and it works fine.

```
output =forecast(rawdf)
```

the question is I can extract muliple dataframe and if I want to use the same function to run over all the dataframe. Because rawdf have a column named DepotName which have multiple unique values.

My aim is to break down the rawdf into multiple dataframes corresponding to the depot and apply the forecast function to all of them individually.

```
DepotList= ['A', 'B']

for Depot in DepotList:
    i=1
    rawdf=rawdf.loc[rawdf.DepotName.isin([DepotList])]
    output[i] =forecast(rawdf)
    i = i+1
```

I havent tried it , as if I am gonna do this for first time. I will appreciate your time and effort to help me accomplish this mission.

Answer (score 0):

Try the same logic with pass DepotList value one by one.

> instead of passing list in **isin()**, pass value by iterating list

```
DepotList= ['A', 'B']
result = []
for Depot in DepotList:

    resultByDepotName =rawdf.loc[rawdf.DepotName.isin(Depot)]
    list = forecast(resultByDepotName)
    result.append(list)
```

result will contains forecast values

> Dont't reassign same dataframe variable of result **rawdf.loc[rawdf.DepotName.isin(Depot)]**

Comment: the forecast function returns a list, so now I have to store those list in each seperate list. How can I store those lists

Comment: you can create an main empty list and append each time in main list

Comment: I amended the code. check it. If answer is correct, Please mark it as correct answer